# Loader constraint violation in Jboss

Tags: java, jboss, cxf

Am running a Web Service Client in JBoss 5.1.0 and I am getting the Following exception

```
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of <bootloader>) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamReader"
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a class loading issue. You most likely have JDK or JBoss provided classes/jars in your application package or you have duplicated jars/classes.